# How to disable Automatic Caption for all your videos on Youtube?

Tags: video, youtube, closed-captions

I manage a Youtube Channel for kids. Youtube just added their automatic English captions on all my videos but the captions are really bad and include swear words.

I know how to remove them one by one on Youtube (unpublish a caption in Edit/Subtitles and CC) but I have 1,400 videos and all of them need to be done.

Is there a way to remove Automatic Caption for all videos?

PS: my videos are embeded using iframe and there are no options/params to hide close captioning

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about usage of some (popular) video hosting plattform, which is neither programming related, nor general computing software, nor professional networking.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a way to do that using the Youtube Data API.